# TTFB increased for no reason

Tags: performance, localhost

I am developing custom theme based on underscores and gutenberg block plugins based on @wordpress/create-block. Suddenly, I observed slowdown in server response, it went from ~400 ms to ~750 ms. I disabled all plugins, which are only three (including mine) with no speed difference. I optimised database. I also inspected xdebug profile file and found that large portion of time is spent on loading WordPress .mo default language files. I disabled loading of language files of theme and my plugin.

I also tried disabling xdebug module on server, but without significant impact. What else could I do to get previous loading speed?

I am working on local stack, "WAMP.Net"
[image]

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question, especially since you don't know what the problem is, just that the effect is higher TTFB, this is an open ended investigation. You need to identify the cause then ask about that instead, otherwise it could be anything. It could even be a background process on your machine that's unrelated to web development using up CPU. You need to profile your website and get hard data on how long things actually take

Comment: You are right. What should I do - share profiling cachegrind file? I inspected it and only concluded that large portions of time is spent on loading WordPress core gettext langugage .mo files and processing them.